# Redirect users based on browser language

Tags: .htaccess

I have this rule in my `.htaccess` file to redirect Dutch users to my subdirectory

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-language} ^nl [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://website.com/nl/ [L,R=301]
```

I want to redirect all other browser languages to the main domain, but now all users get redirected to the subdirectory.

How can I redirect all other languages to the main domain?

Answer (score 0):

Apache's [`RewriteCond`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) directive support the exclamation mark to specify a non-matching pattern:

> You can prefix the pattern string with
>   a '!' character (exclamation mark) to
>   specify a non-matching pattern.

This should work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-language} !^nl [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://website.com/ [L,R=301]
```